# Who is this group of people that have a beef with Shizuo?

Tags: durarara

In episode 25 of *Durarara!!* (the second special episode), three groups of people try to attack Shizuo upon seeing on TV that he and Izaya are fighting.

[image: some ruffians]
[image: ???]
[image: Yellow Scarves]

The first group consists of some of the ruffians that Shizuo beat up in episode 3. Naturally, they'd want revenge on Shizuo. The third group is a bunch of members of the Yellow Scarves. The Yellow Scarves generally perceive Shizuo as standing in the way of their plans for Ikebukuro, so I can see why they'd want to take him out, too.

I do not recognize the second group, though (and I just rewatched the whole first season). Who are they?

Comment: Probably just some random Dollars members. Remember, they're colorless?

Comment: @Hakase That's certainly possible, but Narita generally isn't one to introduce one-off side characters - even most of the random thugs in the show have multiple appearances.